# Upgrading Azure Search SDK from v.5.0.3 to v.9. Search call hangs

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

After upgrading the .net Azure Search SDK to version 9, I am unable to search.  The call just hangs on:

```
    azureSearchIndexClient.Documents.Search(query, parameters);
```

I don't receive an error, everything was working on 5.0.3, I can still create, populate, and delete indexes in version 9.  Without any response, I have little to go on...

Comment: What is the context in which the code is running? ASP.NET classic? ASP.NET Core? As a workaround, can you try calling the async version of the method? In the meantime, we will investigate further.

Comment: @BruceJohnston Thanks for your response, I am running classic .NET Framework 4.6.2.  I tried the async version, now the code hangs on `Task.Wait();`

Comment: What I’m trying to figure out is the threading model of the app that you’re writing. Is it a web app? Console app...? This will help us reproduce the problem.

Comment: It is a .NET MVC Web app.  Also, query="*", and SearchParameters is just some defaults QueryType.Full, IncludeTotalResultsCount=true, Skip=0, Top=50

Comment: Thanks, that narrows it down. While we are investigating, there is one more thing you can try: Instead of using Task.Wait, make the entire call chain async, all the way up to your controller.

Comment: FYI, this issue is being tracked here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/6254

Comment: Another possible workaround while I continue to investigate: Try setting SearchIndexClient.UseHttpGetForQueries to true.

Comment: Setting UseHttpGetForQueries to true actually gave me an error to work with, and then was able to get some results. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in version 9.0.0 of the SDK, tracked here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/6254  It has since been fixed in version 9.0.1, now available for download on NuGet. Version 8.0.0-preview is still affected by this bug as of the time of this writing.

The cause is a missing call to `ConfigureAwait(false)`, which results in deadlock when calling the SDK in the context of an ASP.NET classic app.

The bug only affects the code path used for sending POST requests. That’s why setting `UseHttpGetForQueries` to `true` is an effective workaround. However, this should only be used as a temporary solution until the fix is available, especially if your application sends very large queries that might not fit on the URL query string.

Also note that the deadlock only occurs when blocking on a Task returned from an async method. The synchronous methods of the SDK do this internally. It is recommended practice in ASP.NET to make your controller methods async, as well as all methods that they call that can potentially do I/O, including the methods of the Azure Search SDK. This prevents OS threads from blocking, which greatly increases the scalability of your app. It also avoids issues with potential deadlock due to missing calls to `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the SearchIndexClient.UseHttpGetForQueries = true, gave me an error back to work from, without that the call just hung.

Comment: Glad you're unblocked. Note that this is just a workaround. If you send very large requests, it's better not to use UseHttpGetForQueries. Once a fix for the underlying hang issue is ready, I'll post a more detailed answer here.

Comment: @Ryan is this a workaround or does it just give you an error rather than hanging?

Comment: The error Ryan mentioned is that if you set SearchParameters.Filter to empty string instead of null, the Search call fails with CloudException, but only if UseHttpGetForQueries is set to true.